# What is the appropriate word for something like "to do an action heavily, with a special effort, intensity, pressure, enthusiasm"?

Tags: word-request

1. Someone is playing a piano with his fingers heavily hitting the keys to make a great noise.
2. Someone is painting, his hands energetically waving in all directions. Is there a verb for both of the situations?

To give a notion, it is something like "to do an action heavily, with a special effort, intension, pressure, enthusiasm".

Comment: enthusiastically,. But: He was intensely involved in his painting. He was playing the piano enthusiastically. There's always: with great gusto. And many, many more.

Comment: **Passionately** is a good one if you want to emphasize the emotional aspect, while **vigorously** emphasizes physical effort.

Comment: You asked for a verb, but do you actually want an adverb?

Comment: bang the keys, i.e. to bang on about something, mostly British. The idea of painting and the idea of piano playing in terms of intensity are not related.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to convey the impression of approval of the energy/enthusiasm (either genuine or ironic), the ideal word is **gusto**: see the definition in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gusto). You can make it into an adverbal expression (and that's how it is most often used) by saying **with gusto**.

> He is playing the piano with gusto
>   He is painting with gusto

This expression can be applied to virtually any activity.

Comment: I only saw the "Hot Questions" preview showing the question, and this was my answer as well. It's the perfect word.

Comment: @digitalextremist: agreed

Answer (score 3):

From [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flail)

> **flail**
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 a : to strike with or as if with a flail  ·
>    The bird's wings *flailed* the water.
>
> b : to move, swing, or beat as if wielding a flail  ·
>      *flailing* a club to drive away the insects
>
> 2 : to thresh (grain) with a flail
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to move, swing, or beat like a flail   ·
>      arms *flailing* in the water

So you could **flail** a piano keyboard with your fingers,
or **flail** a canvas with a paintbrush (definition 1a).
Alternatively, you could **flail** your fingers or arms while playing the piano, or **flail** a paintbrush or your arms while painting (definition 1b).
Moreover, according to the definition of the intransitive verb, your fingers or arms can **flail** during either of those activities.

This verb cannot describe *all* actions that one could perform "heavily," however; for example, if you were crushing eggs by stepping on them with a heavy boot, **flail** would seem incongruous; the reader might be confused about whether you were actually wearing the boot or swinging it with your arm.
And if you were pulling weeds up from the ground in your garden energetically, **flail** again would be wrong since you are applying force to pull something *from* the ground rather than to strike something.

---

As pointed out in a comment, one should be careful about the use of **flail** in the context of something artistic. Usually when someone says that a person is flailing their hands on a piano, the implication is that they are not playing well. If you want to convey the sense of playing enthusiastically and *well,* you might want a different word.

Comment: @JavaLatte While the Cambridge Dictionary is usually good, in this case I think it misses several meanings of the word. I have edited the answer to make it clearer how the definitions apply. (Yes, the fingers, arms, or brush _can_ be the subject or object of the verb.)

Comment: Worth mentioning that "flail" does also tend to have connotations of uncoordination. If you are doing something intensely but also very precisely then it might not make sense to describe it as "flailing".

Comment: You can't flail a piano....

Comment: @Lambie In established usage it seems people generally insert a preposition and maybe an adverb, e.g. "flail away at" an instrument. Also see https://books.google.com/books?id=Ro8JAQAAMAAJ&q=%22flail%22+%22piano%22&dq=%22flail%22+%22piano%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8g_a_k7blAhXNJt8KHfwMAx44ChDrATAAegQIBBAB and https://books.google.com/books?id=ek2oj7gqkGoC&pg=PT110&dq=%22flail%22+%22piano%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrwJn-k7blAhXrQd8KHf37B9E4FBDoATABegQICBAC#v=onepage&q=%22flail%22%20%22piano%22&f=false

Comment: @Lambie I will grant that if you want to convey the sense of someone playing enthusiastically and _well,_ "flail" may not be the best choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, here are some verbs

1. striking/to strike the keys, hitting/to hit the keys
2. flapping/to flap one's arms [around]

There's no single verb to cover both meanings.  There are several adverbs you could use to describe the playing or painting.  Such as: playing loudly/noisily/violently, or painting wildly/expressively/violently, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Exert" seems to have the meaning you described.

E.g:

"He exerted himself at/on the piano/the canvas."

"Inflict on/upon" involves violence or agression (sounds sarcastic as in over-enthusiasm, excessive loudness etc)

"He inflicted himself upon the keys / canvas"

Also,

"Applied himself to the piano/canvas with abandon / earnest / all his might / gusto etc"
"Tackled the keys/canvas ..."
"Wrestled with the piano/canvas"

Answer (score 0):

English is a strange language, no?

Depending on context, writing style, ethics and taste you could use many words which describe the passion and vigour in which artists work.

In the same manner you can also elucidate upon the ***grace*** and ***elegance*** with which the pianist is performing the piece, but for your needs these are not valid.

It is all about *context* - just like life, language needs a context in which to be properly understood.

The creative process is just that, an intensely absorbing moment in which the creative is expressing their inner most feeling.

A lot of emotions go into driving our creative moments.

For example, if you would like to show an obsessive process you could say the artist was possessed.

Again, *context* is imperative.

A single word for you needs would be '**pathos**'.

It comes from the Greek and indicates an action done with passion and extreme focus - a purely zen moment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd like to add that the act itself needs to be clarified. You'll have to describe the actual act, ie. The artist's pathos was such that  the canvas warped into a masterpiece. His/Her arms a blur of paint and brush as he/she drew essence out of the world around him/her to show to us mere mortals. The use of 'warp' emphasizes the transformation process itself. Describing his/her actions would define the manner in which the creation process took place. Your readers also need a context with which to populate their imaginations.